# Collectors.groupingBy by two columns doesn't work

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I want to group by two columns using `Collectors.groupingBy`.

I wrote the following:

```
public class TestGroupKey 
{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Item> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Item(1, 1, 1),
            new Item(1, 1, 2),
            new Item(1, 1, 3),
            new Item(1, 2, 1),
            new Item(1, 2, 2),
            new Item(2, 1, 1),
            new Item(2, 2, 1),
            new Item(2, 3, 1),
            new Item(2, 4, 1),
            new Item(2, 4, 2),
            new Item(2, 4, 3),
            new Item(2, 4, 4),
            new Item(3, 1, 1),
            new Item(3, 1, 2),
            new Item(3, 1, 3),
            new Item(3, 1, 4),
            new Item(3, 2, 1),
            new Item(3, 2, 2)
        );

        Map<CustomKey, List<Item>> tupleGrouping = 
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.customKey));
        tupleGrouping.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(entry -> {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                });
    }

    public static class Item {
        public int topLevelId;
        public int secondLevelId;
        public int itemId;
        public CustomKey customKey;

        public Item(int topLevelId, int secondLevelId, int itemId) {
            this.topLevelId = topLevelId;
            this.secondLevelId = secondLevelId;
            this.itemId = itemId;
            this.customKey = new CustomKey(topLevelId, secondLevelId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%d%d%d", this.topLevelId, this.secondLevelId, this.itemId);
        }
    }

    public static class CustomKey {
        public int topLevelId;
        public int secondLevelId;

        public CustomKey(int topLevelId, int secondLevelId) {
            this.topLevelId = topLevelId;
            this.secondLevelId = secondLevelId;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%d%d", this.topLevelId, this.secondLevelId);
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is

```
11 
12 
21 
22 
23 
24 
31 
32
```

But actual result is

```
24
31
23
22
12
21
24
31
31
24
12
32
32
11
11
11
31
```

I think `groupingBy` is not working.

What's the problem with my use of the `CustomKey` Class?

Additionally, nested map key is working:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Item>>> entryGrouping = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(atta1 -> atta1.topLevelId, 
                                       Collectors.groupingBy(atta2 -> atta2.secondLevelId)));
```

Comment: As a side note, `tupleGrouping.entrySet().stream()  .forEach(entry -> {  System.out.println(entry.getKey());  });` is quite convoluted, compared to `tupleGrouping.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);` or `tupleGrouping.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k));`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CustomKey` class doesn't override `Object`'s `equals` method, so `groupingBy` considers two `CustomKey`s to be equal only if they are the same object (which is never true in your example, since you create a new `CustomKey` instance for each `Item`).

```
public static class CustomKey {   
    ...
    @Override
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        // if you override equals, you should also override hashCode
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
        if (other == this)
            return true;
        if (!(other instanceof CustomKey))
            return false;
        CustomKey okey = (CustomKey) other;
        return this.topLevelId == okey.topLevelId && this.secondLevelId == okey.secondLevelId;
    }
    ...
}
```